# rust-lld relocation R_X86_64_32S out of range

Tags: rust, linker, static-linking

I'm trying to linking some code to 0xffff800000000000 but i'm getting the error 'relocation R_X86_64_32S out of range'. I'm linking 64bit code and using '-C relocation-model=large -C code-model=static'. I also use custom linker script. Please tell me how to fix this error.

Linker script:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xffff800000000000;
    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    .bss (NOLOAD) : { *(.bss) *(COMMON) }

    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame) *(.comment) }
}
```